# Generating Ember Components with D3

Tags: javascript, ember.js, svg, d3.js

There is plenty of content online about using Ember.js with D3.js, particularly with making D3 visualizations as Ember Components.  This is something I need to do for a project, but I'm much more familiar with D3 than I am with Ember.

Specifically, I'm using a [D3 force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) whose nodes/vertices need to be interactive.  More specifically, right-clicking a node needs to expose a context menu whose entries have the following requirements:

1. Each menu entry needs to link to a Route of our Ember App
2. Actions and appearance of the menu entries depends upon the data bound to the right-clicked node (and possibly the data bound to the nodes edges and neighbors)

I'm a bit overwhelmed by the number of choices in front of me, but here is my main question:

**How can I generate SVG elements with D3 that link to Ember Routes?**

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @emaillenin Yes! Sorry, I'm in the process of distilling it down.